# How to loop through an xarray and calculating using an index in python

Tags: python

I have a data variable(sst) in an xarray(nino6), first I use enumerate to assign each value of data variable of the array an index, then I want to calculate with the values of data variable using the index. This code calculates with the indizes itself instead of the data variable values, but I just wanted you to show what I tried.

- How can I loop through an index but actually calculating with the values?

```
for i, entry in enumerate(nino6['sst']):
    a=((i-1)+i+(i+1))/3
    ssta.append(a)
```

I apologise for my question is very likely to be really simple (I just started programming), but I searched unsuccesfully here and and on youtube.

Comment: `for i in range(len(nino6['sst'])): ... nino6['sst'][i] ...` is what you are asking for?

Comment: You can just use `entry`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the average of every 3 adjacent numbers in sst, you do it like this:

```
lst = nino6['sst']
ssta = []
for i in range(1,len(lst) - 1):
    a = (lst[i-1] + lst[i] + lst[i+1])/3
    ssta.append(a)
```

Notice that in this implementation, the length of ssta will be smaller than the length of sst by 2 because the first and last numbers do not have flanking numbers.  You can have other variations, where you just get the average of two numbers for the first and last numbers.